# Containers for decks of small cards?

Tags: playing-cards, storage

What sorts of containers have been found to be appropriate for storing large amounts of small cards?  For example, in Descent: Second Edition, There are 155 cards which must be stored, and which measure 41mm by 63mm.  Once they are sleeved (in [these](http://store.fantasyflightgames.com/productdetails.cfm?sku=FFS01)), they no longer fit in their little baggie;  is there some company that makes/sells boxes that fit these small cards?  Are there any commonly available containers that work well to fit these card sizes?

Comment: Are those sizes before or after sleeving the cards? What size are they sleeved? What type of sleeves are you using?

Comment: Also, even if they don't fit in *their* baggie, do they fit in a generic sandwich-sized baggie?

Comment: They may fit in some larger baggie, but some sort of box-type structure seems more ideal to not allowing them to bend/fold out of shape as much as possible...

Comment: I believe the measure is for the cards themselves.  I've updated the question with a link to the sleeves being used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually use those white cardboard boxes to hold large amounts of cards. They come in various sizes. [http://www.amazon.com/BCW-Count--Corrugated-Cardboard-Storage/dp/B000K3XQ8U/](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000K3XQ8U)

Or I create my own boxes using plastic canvas. (sorry i do not have any better links for these at the moment) http://www.crafts-for-all-seasons.com/plastic-canvas-box.html

Comment: Note that those white cardboard boxes are *well* outsized for the kind of cards he's talking about here - his cards are about 1.5"x2.5", a good half-inch smaller than those stock cards in both directions.

Answer (score 2):

You can get little plastic boxes in all kinds of shapes and sizes.

http://www.reallyusefulproducts.co.uk/uk/html/onlineshop/fullrange_rub.php

Also the little clear plastic bags with press-in tops (known as zip-lock)

http://www.ziploc.com/Products/Pages/default.aspx?products=all

For storage of multiple card-based games there are all kinds of small craft storage units with drawers of varying sizes. Personally I use the bags for games with lots of elements such as Agricola, and just keep all the bags of pieces/cards in the Agricola box.

Magic: the Gathering fat-pack boxes are excellent for storing multiple cards in (I have a friend who stores Race for the Galaxy, Gloom, The Great Del Mutay, and some regular playing cards in one) You can get empty ones from ebay or M:tG stores such as Troll and Toad (I'm limited to 2 hyperlinks).